# WinApi owner CComboBox edit window, edit window inside CComboBox

Tags: winapi, combobox, mfc, ownerdrawn, ccombobox

I have a question if is there a possibility to owner CComboBox edit window(top most window of CComboBox/edit window inside a ComboBox)
Because i have made that a CComboBox is OWNERDRAW and I can draw on items( via DrawItem() method)
I also would like to draw on edit item( top most item of CComboBox control)
The problem is that it is edit window and i can type on it( I can't draw on it).
How can i make this window 'drawable'?
any suggestions?
thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use [`GetComboBoxInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb775939.aspx) to get the `hwndItem` (window handle to edit field). Then you simply subclass that one to do what you want :)